# Jquery css to parent element (2 levels up)

Tags: jquery, css, onclick

I have no idea why this isn't working...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.showLink').on('click', function(){
        $(this).parents('.showContainer').css('top', '-2000px');
    });
}):
```

The layout is:

```
<section id="overlay" class="showContainer">
    <div>
        <video></video>
        <div></div>
        <div id="show">
            <a href="#" class="showLink"><i class="fa fa-arrow"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

You can [see it live](http://estradaerik.com) for some debugging if you're interested.

Comment: there is no element called `showContainer`

Comment: `$(this).closest('.showOverlay').css('top', '-2000px');`

Comment: I'm sorry, it actually does have class set to showContainer. I'm very tired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)** in your context rather than using a **[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)**, even though both can do the job.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.showLink').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('.showContainer').css('top', '-2000px');
    });
}): ---> remove the colon over here and replace it with ;
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny OP has a unnecessary colon in his code. Did you notice that.? That might caused a syntax error.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy will this work with css transitions? It seems like it isn't at the moment.

Comment: @jmalais what do you mean.? Do you want to animate it.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Yes, ease it up and out of view.

Comment: @jmalais You just replace `.css('top', '-2000px');` part with `.animate({'top', '-2000px'},"slow");`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46577/discussion-between-jmalais-and-rajaprabhu-aravindasamy)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), it Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.showLink').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.showContainer').css('top', '-2000px');
    });
});
```

Comment: do you know how I could add a transition/animation to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [**closest**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to retrieve only **the first element** matching the query and use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent `<a>` tag default action

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.showLink').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); //use prevent Default on <a> tag.
        $(this).closest('.showContainer').css('top', '-2000px');
    });
});
```

Comment: do you know how I could add a transition/animation to this?

Comment: @jmalais: just replace `.css('top', '-2000px');` with `.animate({'top': '-2000px'},2000);`.

Comment: @jmalais: notice the `{'top': '-2000px'}` with `:`. This is an object.

Comment: do you know why there might be a delay in showing the animation?

Comment: @jmalais: There should not be a delay. It could be that your web page is big and causes delay in your CPU processing.